# how i can read file structure of java project?

Tags: java, file, structure

I have a structure of java-project

```
folder -
        --sub_folder1
          ---file1
          ---file2  
        --sub_folder2
          ---file3
          ---file4
```

How I can read this structure using code?

Comment: Its same reading any folder content.

Answer (score 1):

Here it comes :).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    filesInFolder("./");
}

public static void filesInFolder(String filename) {
    File dir = new File(filename);        
    for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
        System.out.println(child.getAbsolutePath());
        if (child.isDirectory()){
            filesInFolder(child.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String projectRoot = "path to your root folder";
List<File> projectFiles = getProjectFiles(new File(projectRoot));

private List<File> getProjectFiles(File root) {
  List<File> projectFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
  for (File f : root.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isDirectory())
      projectFiles.addAll(getProjectFiles(f));
    else
      projectFiles.add(f);
  }
  return projectFiles; 
}
```

Comment: I'm with you, that's a head scratcher (as to why you should attract a downvote)